# Problema con consulta MySQL en php/Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

En el siguiente `script` muestro una `query` para que haga el beetween de fechas que el usuario seleccione, eso funciona bien, sin embargo mi duda es **cómo lograr que de entrada le muestre al usuario una suma general** de **todas las solicitudes** de **status Atendida** ya que de momento el `WHERE` (`$sWhere`) se ejecuta hasta que el usuario selecciona las fechas y ahí tengo mi validación de status de la consulta, de momento se muestra así (debido a que no me esta haciendo la seleccion del status, solo se ejecuta `$q_book`).

[image: Query]

```
<?php
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date1']));
    $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date2']));

    if (!empty($_POST['date1']) and  !empty($_POST['date1'])){
        list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date1']);
        $date1="$anio-$mes-$dia";
        list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date2']);
        $date2="$anio-$mes-$dia";

        $sWhere="WHERE `status`='Atendida' AND `fecha_solicitud` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";

    } else {
        $sWhere=""; 
    }

    #Conectare a la base de datos
    include("../../includes/dbconfig.php");

    $q_book = $con->query("SELECT status,
    (select SUM(enf.enfriador_una_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_una_pta,
    (select SUM(enf.enfriador_dos_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_dos_pta,    
    (select SUM(enf.enfriador_tres_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_tres_pta,
    (select SUM(maq.total_maquina) from maquinas maq) as tot_vending,
    (select SUM(dis.total_dispensador) from dispensadores dis) as tot_dispensadores,
    (select SUM(fou.total_fountain) from fountain fou) as tot_fountain FROM `solicitudes`
    $sWhere") or die(mysqli_error());
    $v_book = $q_book->num_rows;
    if($v_book > 0){
        while($f_book = $q_book->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_una_pta']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_dos_pta']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_tres_pta']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_dispensadores']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_fountain']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_vending']?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }else{
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "7" class="text-center">No se encontraron solicitudes en el periodo seleccionado</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema se soluciona agregando la condicion que quieres en el `else`.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date1']));
    $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date2']));

    if (!empty($_POST['date1']) and  !empty($_POST['date1'])){
        list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date1']);
        $date1="$anio-$mes-$dia";
        list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date2']);
        $date2="$anio-$mes-$dia";

        $sWhere="WHERE `status`='Atendida' AND `fecha_solicitud` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";

    } else {
        $sWhere="WHERE `status`='Atendida'"; 
    }

    #Conectare a la base de datos
    include("../../includes/dbconfig.php");

    $q_book = $con->query("SELECT status,
    (select SUM(enf.enfriador_una_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_una_pta,
    (select SUM(enf.enfriador_dos_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_dos_pta,    
    (select SUM(enf.enfriador_tres_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_tres_pta,
    (select SUM(maq.total_maquina) from maquinas maq) as tot_vending,
    (select SUM(dis.total_dispensador) from dispensadores dis) as tot_dispensadores,
    (select SUM(fou.total_fountain) from fountain fou) as tot_fountain FROM `solicitudes`
    $sWhere") or die(mysqli_error());
    $v_book = $q_book->num_rows;
    if($v_book > 0){
        while($f_book = $q_book->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_una_pta']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_dos_pta']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_tres_pta']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_dispensadores']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_fountain']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $f_book['tot_vending']?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }else{
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "7" class="text-center">No se encontraron solicitudes en el periodo seleccionado</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
?>
```